# Copying vertex coordinates from one line into another with same geometry type

Tags: qgis-3, copy

I have the following QGIS version.

[image: example]

How is possible to copy the vertex data information from a line into another line? Maybe a certain plugin shall be used for this purpose.

The data are 407 points with `(X,Y)` coordinates tuples. I need to copy this information to another line with the same geometry type.

Comment: If you select the lines and copy them into the other layer, the copies will have the same vertices. Is that what you're trying to do? Or do you need to edit the vertices of existing lines in the second layer?

Comment: Yes man! Indeed, I employed that procedure. Thanks for comment!